# Proof verification: $a_1=2$, $a_{n+1}=3+\frac{a_n}{2}$ is increasing and bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

For base case, $a_2=3+\frac{a_1}{2}=4>a_1$

For $n=k$, let $a_{k+1}>a_k$

Adding 3 on both sides after dividing by 2,

$$3+\frac{a_{k+1}}{2}>3+\frac{a_k}{2}$$
$$a_{k+2}>a_{k+1}$$

Hence the sequence is increasing.

How can I show that the sequence is bounded?

Comment: The answers have shown $a_n \leq 6$. One way to figure this out without guessing or explicitly solving the whole recurrence is to use the following two facts. A bounded monotone sequence converges. The limit of a convergent sequence of the form $x_{k+1}=f(x_k)$ is a fixed point of $f$ if $f$ is continuous. Hence you should look for a fixed point of $x \mapsto 3+\frac{x}{2}$; it is easy to see that the only fixed point is $6$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show inductively that $\;a_n\le6\;$ :

$$a_{n+1}:=3+\frac{a_n}2\stackrel{\text{Ind. Hyp.}}\le3+\frac62=6$$

As for your proof of increasing: it is fine, but you need to show, or in fact remark as it is almost trivial, that the sequence is *positive*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use induction again to show that $a_k < 6$, which is suggested by the trick of considering the equation $a= 3+ \frac{a}{2}$ and solving for $a$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=b_n+6$. Then
$$ b_{n+1}+6=3+\frac{b_n}{2}+3 $$
is equivalent to $b_{n+1}=\frac{b_n}{2}$ or to $b_n=\frac{b_1}{2^{n-1}}$.
 Since $a_1=2$ we have $b_1=-4$, hence
$ b_n = -\frac{8}{2^n} $  and
$$\boxed{ a_n = \color{red}{6-\frac{8}{2^n}} }$$
Now the claim is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
a_{n+1}&=3+\frac {a_n}2\\
a_{n+1}-6&=\frac 12 \left(a_n-6\right)\\
b_n&=\frac 12 b_{n-1}=\cdots =\frac 1{2^{n-1}}b_1&&(b_n=a_n-6)\\
a_n-6&=\frac 1{2^{n-1}}(\underbrace{\;a_1\;}_{=2}-6)\\
\color{red}{a_n}&\color{red}{=6-\frac 8{2^n}}
\end{align}$$
which is increasing and bounded (at $6$) as $n\to \infty$.